# Parent li in dropdown not changing color off hover

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I have an `<li>` that on hover shows a `<ul>` beneath it. I finally got the borders aligned but now for some reason the `li:hover` color won't change back when I hover off of it. What seems to be happening is that when the `<ul>` is active the parent `<li>` remains hovered according to CSS.

Here's a jsFiddle showing what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/

When the `<ul>` is showing and the parent `<li>` isn't being hovered over, I'd like the parent `<li>` to have the same background color and border color of the `<li>` elements within the `<ul>`. How can I best fix this while maintaining the border integrity of the entire `<div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could by changing

```
#nav li#parent:hover {
```

to

```
#nav li#parent a:hover {
```

Also you could then put:

```
#nav li#parent:hover {
    background-color:#CCD9FF;
    border-color: #99B3FF;
}
```

To keep it looking consistent. http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/4/

**update:** whoops. Seems also needed to move the `border-*` and `border-radius-*` into its own. (from `parent` to `parent a`) http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/8/

from:

```
#nav li#parent{
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left:1px solid #FFF;
}

#nav li#parent:hover{
    background-color:#CCD9FF;
    border-color: #99B3FF;
}
```

to:

```
#nav li#parent {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#nav li#parent a {
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left:1px solid #FFF;
}

#nav li#parent:hover a {
    background-color:#CCD9FF;
    border-color: #99B3FF;
}
```

Comment: Those were the only changes?  Nice solution.  No jQuery.  Far exceeds the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @bozdoz actually only the first one was needed. The second change was because it didn't look right to me.

Comment: It seems as if some of the elements shift a bit when I hover between an element's `<li>` and `<a>`. For example, hovering over `li#parent` then hovering over `li#parent a` shifts the ul down a bit. Same for the `<li>` elements in `ul#children`.

Comment: @tvalent2 I've updated my post to fix this. I didn't move all of the border properties like i should have so the parent would have the nice light blue background. http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/8/ should be fixed now.

Comment: @tvalent2 There are other various inconsistencies relating to borders. Personally I think the css is far too complex but http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/9/ is a version with them all fixed.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Works beautifully; and this has been very helpful. But I assume you'd recommend jQuery?

Comment: @tvalent2 I would recommend jQuery for javascript related questions. This shouldn't be one of them. (unless you want to support the old outdated browsers that no-one should use.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not opposed to using some jQuery, you could do this

```
$('ul#children').hover(
   function(){
       $(this).parent('li').css('background-color','#CCD9FF');
    },   
    function(){
        $(this).parent('li').css('background-color','');
    } 
);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/1/

Answer (score 0):

How's this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luryf/5/)

I made it so the #parent li didn't wrap around the ul, changed some css, most importantly, this one:

```
#nav li:hover + ul, #nav ul ul:hover {
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**update**

and added this:

```
#nav li, #nav ul:hover #parent {
    background-color:#CCD9FF;
}

#nav ul:hover #parent {
border-left: 1px solid #99B3FF;
border-right: 1px solid #99B3FF;
    border-top: 1px solid #99B3FF;
}
```

Before

```
#nav li#parent:hover { ... }
```

Comment: This looks close, but is there a way to not have the elements in `ul#children li` shrink a bit when you hover from `li#parent`? Once you're in the `<ul>` and hover over its elements it isn't noticeable but when you shift from #parent to #children it's slight.

Comment: absolutely: Add the border-bottom property to the #nav ul:hover #parent selector.  Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Luryf/7/

Comment: @bozdoz a `<ul>` element inside a `<ul>` element? is that valid markup?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  Ask the guy who wrote it.

Comment: I learned this from Google's HTML, CSS, and JavaScript from the Ground Up (http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/). Particularly this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mgyfwYKpmQ