# remove CSS formating of parent <li> when hovering over child <li> in dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am messing around with a pure CSS dropdown menu and I've noticed that when you hover over the top `<li>` element, it shows the button style, but when you hover over the child `<li>` element in the dropdown menu, the top `<li>` element retains the "button state". I want the "button state" of the parent `<li>` element to be gone when I hover over any of the items in the dropdown menu. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AQZ4V/1/

Comment: Wouldn't you want this anyway? It still shows the user what page he/she is on. Why not changing your hover state to a slightly darker/lighter color to show on hover?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815395/parent-li-in-dropdown-not-changing-color-off-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:hover` pseudo-selector applies to elements even if child element is hovered. I can suggest you to apply the "button styles" to the `<a>` element in the top `<li>`s.

```
#nav .current a, #nav li > a:hover {
```

instead of

```
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AQZ4V/2/)

Comment: Why is the parent <li> still considered hovered in the case of "#nav li:hover > a" even after I hover over the child <li> element instead?

Answer (score 4):

this works in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/bn9EC/